# Database query : Hibernate without mapping

Tags: hibernate, join, hql, criteria

I've a lot of tables in my database, and as a consequence, a lot lot join.
Previously i did my queries with native SQL but now I'm using hibernate (with HQL or criteria).

My question is : Is it required to map files for my join on select queries ?

I didn't find any official documentation about it.
Perhaps there is any tips or tricks to make them.

Thanks in advance & sorry for my bad english (I'm a begginer in this language).

Comment: What do you mean by "map files"?

Comment: Sorry, for me, "map" is add annotations in POJO like "@ManyToMany" or in XML where join is hardcorded/prepared

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referencing Entity classes in both HQL and Criteria, you have to set up entities adequately, which includes mapping relations between the entities.